# LXDE: keybinding for single key not working

Tags: lxde

I am trying to bind `lxterminal` to the `windows` key on my keyboard. The problem is, it only works for key kombination, such as `W-r`. But I would like to use `W` only.

I have added the following in to the `<keyboard>` section of my `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

```
<keybind key="W">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>LXterminal</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>lxterminal</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

but this does not work. Can somebody please help?

UPDATE:
I have just realized, that `<keybind key="W">` refers to the `W` key (capital w), and not to the Windows key. This is illogical, because key combination `W-e` refers to `Windows key + e`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I have to use `Super_L` instead of `W`

```
<keybind key="Super_L">
  <action name="Execute">
    <startupnotify>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <name>LXterminal</name>
    </startupnotify>
    <command>lxterminal</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!! Tks!